# What app is this screenshot from? Is it only a mockup?

Tags: ios, applications, screen-capture

This screenshot was posted by somebody in my Twitter feed on the day Steve Jobs died. It was the author's tribute to him. He received many @replies asking what app this was, but nobody received a reply.

What app is this screenshot of?

[image: To-do app (?)]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's a screenshot from [Reminders](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#reminders), part of iOS 5

Comment: It's not the final released version, perhaps it was one of the betas, as that date bar at the bottom doesn't exist on my iPhone 4S.

Comment: There will be if you view by date.

Comment: D'oh, of course. I retract my previous statement. :)

Comment: Come on, you just wanted to mention you got the 4S :)

Comment: No, just thought people would want to know it's a "blessed' device, not running the GM or anything weird. ;P